# How can we load json string into extjs4 arraystore?

Tags: java, json, extjs

**Here is my model :-**

```
Ext.define('attributeModel', {
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields   : ['attributeName']     
    idProperty: 'attributeName'
});
Ext.define('entityModel', {
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields   : ['entityName']     
    idProperty: 'entityName',
    hasMany: {model: 'attributeModel', name:  'attributes'}
});
```

**This is my store:-**

```
Ext.define('entityStore', {
extend      : 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
model       : 'entityModel',
storeId:'entityStoreId',
proxy: {
      type: 'memory',
      reader: {
           type: 'json'
       }
    }
```

});

**These are my Bean classes in Java:-**

**EntityVO.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EntityVO { 

 private String entityName;
 private ArrayList<AttributeVO> attrList;

 public ArrayList<AttributeVO> getAttrList() {
    return attrList;
 }
 public void setAttrList(ArrayList<AttributeVO> attrList) {
    this.attrList = attrList;
 }
 public String getEntityName() {
    return entityName;
 }
 public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
    this.entityName = entityName;
 }          
}
```

**AttributeVO.java**

```
 public class AttributeVO{  

  private String attributeName;
  public String getAttributeName() {
     return attributeName;
  }
  public void setAttributeName(String attributeName) {
    this.attributeName = attributeName;
  }         
}
```

I am filling `EntityVO` values in `java` and I am creating a `json` string using `ObjectMapper` and sending it as a `response` to `Extjs`.

When I am decoding my `json` string at `extjs` and setting it to `entityStore` it is not loading any data and it is not throwing any error. Is there any way we can load data which is present in beans into `extjs` store?

```
var store = Ext.create('entityStore');
store.loadData(responseJson); //not working
```

**json response:**

```
{
"entityList": [{
    "entityName": "entity1",
    "attrList": [{
        "attributeName": "attr1"
    }, {
        "attributeName": "attr2"
    }]
}, {
    "entityName": "entity2",
    "attrList": [{
        "attributeName": "attr1"
    }]
}]
```

}

Comment: What is your `responseJson`? Can you please update the `value` you get in `responseJson`?

Comment: @KrutiPatel i have updated the value.

Comment: You can go through this thread(might be helpful): https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?300754-HasMany-associations-not-loaded-from-ArrayStore

Answer (score 0):

probably you get your *responseJson* from ajax request's callback method. if stuation is this, try that;

```
var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(responseJson.responseText);
store.loadData(resp);
```

you seems to forgot define to root attribute of your store. you can specify your root attribute in store defination like that;

```
  reader: {
       type: 'json',
       root: 'entityList'
   }
```

or you can pass value like that;

```
store.loadData(resp.entityList);
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all you need to decode the json payload

```
var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(responseJson.responseText);
```

The next operation necessary to add the element inside your store (that is an 'Ext.data.ArrayStore') is to simply use the "add" command

```
store.add(resp);
```

here is a very simple fiddle example
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12f7

Fiddle code:

```
Ext.define('attributeModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['attributeName'],
idProperty: 'attributeName'
});

Ext.define('entityModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['entityName'],
idProperty: 'entityName',
hasMany: {
    model: 'attributeModel',
    name: 'attributes'
}
});


Ext.define('entityStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
model: 'entityModel',
storeId: 'entityStoreId',
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});

Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',
launch: function() {
    var store = Ext.create('entityStore');
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
        "entityList": [{
            "entityName": "entity1",
            "attrList": [{
                "attributeName": "attr1"
            }, {
                "attributeName": "attr2"
            }]
        }, {
            "entityName": "entity2",
            "attrList": [{
                "attributeName": "attr1"
            }]
        }]

    });
    var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(jsonStr);
    var countBefore = store.count();
    store.add(resp);
    var countAfter = store.count();
    Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'store before add count: ' + countBefore + ', now: ----' + countAfter + ' ' + JSON.stringify(store.getAt(0).data));

}
});
```